# How does the word distribution of a document relate to its topic distribution in LDA?

Tags: latent-variable, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

Suppose I trained an LDA model (latent dirichlet allocation). This gives me for each topic a word-distribution. Now I receive a new document and I want to calculate what the distribution of topics is for this new distribution. My only guess for how to do this would be the following:

Say we have 30 topics and the corpus consists of 10,000 unique words. Consider the word-distributions of the 20 topics as 20 vectors in this 10,000 dimensional word space. Also view the word-counts of the document as a vector in this 10,000 dimensional word space. Now project the document "word-vector" on the subspace spanned by the 20 topic "word-vectors". Then normalize the result.
Is this correct?

edit: on the bright side, I did earn the tumbleweed badge on this one

Comment: I was going to suggest cosine similarity. Now that I think about it, it would have been exactly same as what you did. 

Also, everyone down here has the tumbleweed badge, I think.